# Smoothscroll.js blocking scroll on opera but if removed breaks sticky header

Tags: jquery, scroll, sticky, smooth-scrolling

sorry if this has been previously resolved, I looked but couldn't find a solution. I am very new to jQuery, usually relying on the template's functionality.

Problem:
1- smoothscroll.js breaks scroll in Opera.
2- getting rid of it fixes scroll in Opera but breaks sticky header in all browsers
3- the version of Smoothscroll I have is not the latest. As soon as I update it to the latest one, scroll gets fixed in Opera but sticky header still breaks

Here are the links:
Without a link to smoothscroll: http://econocard.ca/demo/no-smoothscroll.html

With template's default smoothscroll: /demo/smoothscroll-enabled.html

With the latest smoothscroll: demo/smoothscroll-latest.html

I am ok with no smoothscroll, it seems to be buggy and unnecessary in general, but I need to fix sticky header.

Comment: the code seems to be ok, I believe your issue could be with the CSS included in the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There problem is Opera for whatever reason, isn't adding the `style="height: auto;"` to the `<html>` element. All other browsers are doing this automatically from some unknown script. I tried tracing which function was applying this but it's not obvious at all.

Here's some solutions you can do to fix it:

1. Add a script to the bottom of the page which adds these style manually (probably the best solution):

   ```
    <script>
     $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('html').css({"height": "auto"});
     })
    </script>
   ```
2. Remove the CSS entry (`style.css:70`) which applies a fixed height of 100% to the `<html>` element (this will definitely fix the problem but may cause other issues with your preloader animation).

   ```
   html,
   body {
     width: 100%;
     overflow-x: hidden;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The Css solution worked perfect, no preloader issues.

```
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Thanks!